# Sounddevice with porcupine not response

Tags: python-3.x

The first version of this code was based on pvrecoder but then errors began to occur and connected sounddevice and the code stopped responding. Doesn't throw any errors. Help me please!

My code:

```
import pvporcupine
import queue
import sounddevice as sd
import yaml
import sys

with open('tokens.yaml', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    data = yaml.safe_load(f)
    PICOVOICE_TOKEN = data[0].get("Picovoice")

porcupine = pvporcupine.create(
  access_key=PICOVOICE_TOKEN,
  keyword_paths=[r'C:\Users\lsiba\OneDrive\Desktop\CODS\jarvis\jarvis_windows.ppn'],
  sensitivities=[1]
)
#print(sd.query_devices())
device_info = sd.query_devices(sd.default.device[0], 'input')
samplerate = int(device_info['default_samplerate'])
q = queue.Queue()

def recordCallback(indata, frames, time, status):
    if status:
        print(status, file=sys.stderr)
    q.put(bytes(indata))

def wake_word():
    with sd.RawInputStream(dtype='int16',
                        blocksize = 256,
                        channels=1,
                        callback=recordCallback):
            
        global cont
        cont = True
        while cont==True:
            data = q.get() 
            keyword_index = porcupine.process(data)
            if keyword_index >= 0:
                cont = False
                print("WAKE")
                return "WAKE"

wake_word()
```

I also tried connecting pyaudio and that worked too